# How to calculate standard deviation with pandas for each row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have my dataframe:

```
d = {'y1': [0,4.2, 6.7, 5.27, 3.45,3.45, 1.22], 'y2': [2, 8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

I want to calculate the standard deviation for each row (as in between 2 data points). I have used this :

```
df.stack().std()
```

But this gives me the standard deviation for the whole dataframe i am afraid. I just want to get the error for each data point and plot the error bars, so i am looking to calculate the standard deviation for each row. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`.std(axis=1)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) instead, this will result in a `Series` with as indices the indices of your dataframe, and as values, the standard deviation of the two values in the corresponding columns:

```
>>> df.std(axis=1)
0    1.414214
1    2.687006
2    1.626346
3    1.223295
4    1.025305
5    1.732412
6    1.965757
dtype: float64
```